# Segfault when dereferencing pointer set by pthread_join

Tags: c, pthreads, segmentation-fault

I have the following code for testing how to "implement return values" using `pthread_exit()` and `pthread_join()`.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <pthread.h>

void* busy() {

    int returnValue = 2;
    pthread_exit((void*)&returnValue);

}


int main() {

    void* retVoidPtr = NULL;
    int* retValPtr = NULL;
    int retVal;

    pthread_t busyThread;
    pthread_create(&busyThread, NULL, busy, NULL);
    pthread_join(busyThread, &retVoidPtr);
    retValPtr = (int*) retVoidPtr;
    retVal = *retValPtr;

    printf("Busy thread returned %d\n", retVal);

    return 0;

}
```

The program compiles fine, but never gets to the `printf` statement. A segfault occurs at the line `retVal = *retValPtr`. Using gdb, I can see that the `retValPtr` pointer is no longer `NULL` but when I try `print *retValPtr` gdb says "Cannot access memory at address 0x...". Any suggestions where I'm going wrong?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A C function can't return a pointer to a value on the stack under the *best* of circumstances. If that stack is the stack of a thread that has terminated, though, we're talking complete disaster, as the memory for that thread's stack may no longer be mapped -- that appears to be the case here.

Your thread function needs to return a pointer to data that will remain valid when the thread terminates: a global variable, or a block obtained from `malloc()`.

Comment: Thanks for your explanation. Should have looked at the `pthread_exit` man page more carefully.